# Jenkins - selecting a downstream job as a checkbox parameter

Tags: jenkins, extended-choice-parameter

Lets say there is project A which has a checkbox parameter called jobs. In the jobs parameter there are three downstream jobs B, C and D. Now, is it possible that if I select C and D only those two downstream jobs get triggered?

I know I can do it by calling remote API for those two jobs as part of the build step (shell), but I wanted to see if there is an option from downstream jobs itselfs.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a freestyle or pipeline job? This is simple in a pipeline job. In a freestyle job, you might be able to use the Conditional Build Step plugin, but I don't know if you can trigger post-build steps with the conditions, or just build steps. You would need to test and see if this lets you check the conditions where you need to.

Comment: Do you have an example in pipeline job? I dont mind trying it out.

Comment: I don't have an example, but it is just groovy code. Just use logic: `if (param.JOBS == 'B') {trigger job B}`.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you configuring a conditional step in job **A**

You can modify job **A** with new choice parameters for each job, for example:

1. name: build_C; choices:yes/no;
2. add a *conditional step (single)* in job **A** with *run*: **execute shell** and *Builder*: **Trigger/call builds on other projects**
3. In the run sections with execute shell add a script to check if your parameter **build_C** is *yes* or *no*, for example `if [ $build_C == "YES" ]; then exit 0; else exit 1;fi`
4. In the **Trigger/call builds on other projects** section *Projects to build* specify your job **C**

Now when you start the job A with parameters, if you choose **build_C** as **yes** - job C will run. If **no** - job C will be skipped.